# Mule ESB Two JSON arrays, merge one array into another with Dataweave

Tags: java, mule, esb, dataweave

I am using Mule ESB and I need to use the ItemID from JSON1 and qty from JSON2 which then create a new JSON payload.

Here is JSON 1:

```
[{
  "itemid": "160544",
  "sku": "L45-075-14",
  "qty": "1.0000"
  }, { 
  "itemid": "160545",
  "sku": "063-0159-881",
  "qty": "1.0000"
}]
```

Here is JSON 2:

```
[{
  "sku": "603-0159-881",
  "qty": "4.0000"
  }, {
  "sku": "L45-075-14",
  "qty": "5.0000"
}]
```

Here is my dataweave code:

```
 %dw 1.0
 %output application/java
 ---
 flowVars.SSRGetOrderItems map (action, index) -> {
                                    (action.itemid) : action.qty,
                                    (flowVars.SSRCreateStarshipItems filter $.sku == action.sku)
                                }
```

I do not need the SKU in my final Java list, I just need the itemid and qty, joined on the sku key. (See Below desired output)

Desired Output:

```
 [{"160544"-"5.0000"}, {"160545"-"4.0000"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Hashmap lookup instead filter for better performance. It can be done in two ways assuming output `[{"160544":"5.0000"}, {"160545":"4.0000"}]`

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%var skuLookup =  flowVars.SSRCreateStarshipItems groupBy $.sku
---
flowVars.SSRGetOrderItems map {
    ($.itemid) : skuLookup[$.sku][0].qty
}
```

or

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%var skuLookup = {(flowVars.SSRCreateStarshipItems map {
    ($.sku) : $.qty
})}
---
flowVars.SSRGetOrderItems map {
    ($.itemid) : skuLookup[$.sku]
}
```

Hope this helps.